# How to fill textbox with data (its database value) in ajax asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to show a data in a textbox that I want to extract from the database. I'm using ajax for this. I have a total of 9 different values from a column called "Urun_gtip". And I want to show these values separately in 9 labels. How can I show them in the view?
Thanks.

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Urun_Ad()
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["APP_LOG_Con"].ConnectionString))
    {
        object ret = null;
        string query = "select distinct a.Urun_Gtip from RelationTBL a select distinct a.Urun_Gtip from RelationTBL a ";

        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
        {
            cmd.Connection = con;

            con.Open();
            ret = Serialize(cmd.ExecuteReader());
            con.Close();
        }

        return Json(ret, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

View:

```
   <div class="modal-body" id="modalData2">
   <div class="row" tabindex="-1">
   <div class=".col-8 .col-sm-6" style="margin-left:25px;">
   <label for="Urun_GID" style="color:#dc3545;">Ürün</label>
   <input class="form-control" name="Urun_Gtip" id="Urun_GID" disabled>
   </div>
  <div class=".col-4 .col-sm-6">
  <label for="Adet" style="color:#dc3545; margin-left:6px;">Adetleri giriniz: 
  </label>
  <input class="form-control" onfocus="this.value=''" name="Adet" id="Adet">
  </div>
   </div>

// I have same 9 row (count of query result is 9)
```

jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
          url: "/Müsavir/Urun_Ad",
          type: "GET",
          success: (data) => {
             // How can I set data to textbox value here?
          }
       });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just parse the json data you are getting and add them using a loop:

```
$.ajax({
          url: "/Müsavir/Urun_Ad",
          type: "GET",
          success: (data) => {
             var json = JSON.parse(data);
             for(var i=0; i<json.length;i++)
                $('#somecontainer').append('<label>' + json.urun_gtip + '</label>);
          }
       });
```